# Store and visualize super large social graph both on desk application and online

Tags: javascript, graph, nosql, bigdata

anyone knows about the most efficient way to store and visualize a large graph with several million edges?

I'm aware of Gephi. But it can't visualize such a big data set.(at least in my laptop with 4G memory. It always crashes or is out of memory.) Is there any other software can handle it? Or there might be other tricks about the Gephi to visualize such a big data set.

I use the python lib, NetworkX, to deal with the graph, it works well. But storing the graph is another issue. So far I use text file and the binary file pickle to store the graph. It is fine. But my research also involves in the calculation between the node pairs, which may be up to 100 million pairs. Calculating them takes time, but storing and querying them seems take more. I try the traditional database, like Postgre, but it is very slow to for both store and query. I also try a NoSQL db, Neo4j, which is for storing graph data, but dumping the whole graph and the calculating results into it are super slow. It took about 20hrs to store 2/5 of the data and then I got an error from nowhere. Could someone recommend me some other powerful tools to get rid of this?

Plus, my boss asked me to build an online visualization version of my research result on the graph. From the former experience on the graph, I don't think the common js libraries can deal such a big data set. I know I do need to build some hierarchy of the data for visualization and interaction, but what kind of architecture or framework, from the DB to the browser-side library shall I employ?

PS I'm not an original computer science guy so my knowledge on the techniques is limited, misusing terms may be inevitable.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Yeah, I can't imagine D3 trying to run with several million points of data.  I'm not sure a web-based version is feasible, without some creative ways of reducing your dataset.

Comment: Whatever graph visualisation software you choose you're going to have to do some major data reduction before you visualise anything.  With the volumes of information you indicate, there simply isn't enough screen space to display your whole data set; not on any screen.  So you might as well choose your favourite visualisation software and reduce your data set to fit.